# Me ayudarían por favor pasando este código que esta en Java a C#

Tags: java, c#

```
    //Clase de excepcion para errores del analizador
class Excepciones extends Exception {
    String errStr; // Muestra el error
    public Excepciones(String str) {
        errStr = str;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return errStr;
    }
}

class Analizador {
    //estos son los tipos de token
    final int NINGUNO = 0;
    final int DELIMITADOR = 1;
    final int VARIABLE = 2;
    final int NUMERO = 3;
    //estos son los tipos de errores de sintaxis
    final int SYNTAXIS = 0;
    final int PARENTESIS = 1;
    final int SINEXP = 2;
    final int DIVENTRECERO = 3;
    //Este token indican fin de la expresion
    final String FINEXP = "\0";

    private String exp; // hace referencia a la cadena de expresion
    private int expIndice; // indica el indice actual de la expresion
    private String token; // contiene token actual
    private int tipoToken; // contien tipo de token

    // metodo de punto de entrada del analizador
    public double evaluar(String cadenaExp) throws Excepciones{
        double resultado;
        exp = cadenaExp;
        expIndice = 0;
        obtieneToken();
        if(token.equals(FINEXP)){
            obtieneError(SINEXP); // no hay expresion presente
        } 
        // analiza y evalua la expresion
        resultado = evaluarExp2();
        if(!token.equals(FINEXP)){ // el ultimo token debe ser FINEXP
            obtieneError(SYNTAXIS);
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    // metodo para suma o resta
    private double evaluarExp2() throws Excepciones{
        char op;
        double resultado;
        double resultadoParcial;
        resultado = evaluarExp3();
        while((op = token.charAt(0)) == '+' || op == '-') {
            obtieneToken();
            resultadoParcial = evaluarExp3();
            switch(op) {
                case '-':
                    resultado = resultado - resultadoParcial;
                break;
                case '+':
                    resultado = resultado + resultadoParcial;
                break;
            } 
        }
        return resultado;
    }

// metodo para multiplicacion, division o modulo
private double evaluarExp3() throws Excepciones{
    char op;
    double resultado;
    double resultadoParcial;
    resultado = evaluarExp4();
    while((op = token.charAt(0)) == '*' || op == '/' || op == '%'){
        obtieneToken();
        resultadoParcial = evaluarExp4();
        switch(op) {
            case '*':
                resultado = resultado * resultadoParcial;
            break;
            case '/':
                if(resultadoParcial == 0.0){
                    obtieneError(DIVENTRECERO);
                }
                resultado = resultado / resultadoParcial;
            break;
            case '%':
                if(resultadoParcial == 0.0){
                    obtieneError(DIVENTRECERO);
                }
                resultado = resultado % resultadoParcial;
            break;
        }
    }
    return resultado;
  }

// metodo que evalua un exponente
private double evaluarExp4() throws Excepciones{
    double resultado;
    double resultadoParcial;
    double ex;
    int t;
    resultado = evaluarExp5();
    if(token.equals("^")){
        obtieneToken();
        resultadoParcial = evaluarExp4();
        ex = resultado;
        if(resultadoParcial == 0.0) {
            resultado = 1.0;
        }else{
            for(t=(int)resultadoParcial-1; t > 0; t--){
                resultado = resultado * ex;
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

// metodo que evalua operador unario + ó -.
private double evaluarExp5() throws Excepciones{
    double resultado;
    String  op;
    op = "";
    if((tipoToken == DELIMITADOR) && token.equals("+") || token.equals("-")){
        op = token;
        obtieneToken();
    }
    resultado = evaluarExp6();
    if(op.equals("-")){
        resultado = -resultado;
    }
    return resultado;
}

// metodo que procesa los parentesis
private double evaluarExp6() throws Excepciones{
    double resultado;
    if(token.equals("(")) {
        obtieneToken();
        resultado = evaluarExp2();
        if(!token.equals(")")){
            obtieneError(PARENTESIS);
        }
        obtieneToken();
    }else{
        resultado = valor();
    }
    return resultado;
}

//Metodo que obtiene el valor de un numero
private double valor() throws Excepciones{
    double resultado = 0.0;
    switch(tipoToken){
        case NUMERO:
            try {
              resultado = Double.parseDouble(token);
            } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
              obtieneError(SYNTAXIS);
            }
            obtieneToken();
            break;
        default:
            obtieneError(SYNTAXIS);
            break;
    }
    return resultado;
}

//metodo que devuelve mensaje en caso de error
private void obtieneError(int error) throws Excepciones{
    String[] err = {
        "ERROR DE SYNTAXIS",
        "PARENTESIS NO BALANCEADOS",
        "NO EXISTE EXPRESION",
        "DIVISION POR CERO"
    };
    throw new Excepciones(err[error]);
}

//obtiene la siguiente token
private void obtieneToken(){
    tipoToken = NINGUNO;
    token = "";
    //Busca el final de la expresion
    if(expIndice == exp.length()){
        token = FINEXP;
        return;
    }
    //Omite el espacio en blanco
    while(expIndice < exp.length() && Character.isWhitespace(exp.charAt(expIndice))){
        ++expIndice;
    }
    //Espacio en blanco termina la expresion
    if(expIndice == exp.length()){
        token = FINEXP;
        return; 
    }
    if(esDelimitador(exp.charAt(expIndice))){ // es operador
        token += exp.charAt(expIndice);
        expIndice++;
        tipoToken = DELIMITADOR;
    }else if(Character.isLetter(exp.charAt(expIndice))) { // es variable
        while(!esDelimitador(exp.charAt(expIndice))){
            token += exp.charAt(expIndice);
            expIndice++;
            if(expIndice >= exp.length()){
                break;
            }
        }
    tipoToken = VARIABLE;
    }else if(Character.isDigit(exp.charAt(expIndice))){ // es numero
        while(!esDelimitador(exp.charAt(expIndice))){
            token += exp.charAt(expIndice);
            expIndice++;
            if(expIndice >= exp.length()){
                break;
            }
        }
    tipoToken = NUMERO;
    }else{ //caracter desconocido termina la expresion
        token = FINEXP;
        return;
    } 
}


//Devuelve true si c es un delimitardor
private boolean esDelimitador(char c){
    if (("+-/*^=%()".indexOf (c) != -1)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Este código lo encontré en internet y lo quiero pasar a c# les agradecería mucho si se toman el tiempo de ayudarme, gracias. Se trata de crear un programa que permita evaluar expresiones como esta:  12-10/3+20-(50-20)*3. Al momento ya he adelantado una parte pero tengo problema en los métodos para evaluar las expresiones los cuales les muestro a continuación.. Además les debo decir que todavía no se muy bien programar por lo que se me hacen complicadas este tipo de cosas de ante mano muchas gracias al que disponga de tiempo y pueda darme una mano en este problema que tengo.

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour], tu pregunta pudiera terminar cerrada pues no es clara, ¿qué has intentado?, ¿que dudas tienes?, ¿qué fallos has obtenido al momento?

Comment: No entiendo de donde viene tu variable token y porque la tienes en un while si solo quieres validar el primer caracter de tu cadena.

Comment: Debes mejorar la pregunta, porque cualquiera leeria la pregunta y no los comentarios para ver si agregaste algo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que a tu pregunta le falta información para saber de donde viene tu info. que el `while` esta evaluando, pero basado en lo que pusiste te lo paso a c#

```
private double evaluarExp2()
        {
        char op;
        double resultado = 0;
        double resultadoParcial;
        string token = "+102500";
```

Entiendo que todo el tiempo le pasas info. al `while` para evaluar, con el método:

```
substring(caracterInicial, CantidadDeCaracteres)
```

El signo `?` es para que evalúe que la cadena no sea `null` y quiera ejecutar un método sobre `null`, lo cual lanzaría excepción.

```
        while (token?.Substring(1, 1).Equals("+") || token?.Substring(1, 1).Equals("-"))
        {
```

Convertimos el caracter en `char` y los podemos evaluar con el `switch` lo mas parecido a tu código original.

```
            char r = Convert.ToChar(token?.Substring(1, 1));
            //obtieneToken();
            resultadoParcial = evaluarExp3();
            switch (r)
            {
                case '-':
                    resultado = resultado - resultadoParcial;
                    break;
                case '+':
                    resultado = resultado + resultadoParcial;
                    break;
            }
        }
        return resultado; //introducir el código aquí
    }
```